# How can I allow a custom taxonomy for certain roles?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, editor

Im trying to only show a taxonomy for the `editor` and `administrator` but I haven't found a solution on SO or here.  The closest thing I was able to find was [How do I remove a taxonomy from Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249694/how-do-i-remove-a-taxonomy-from-wordpress) on SO.  What is the proper way to only allow the taxonomy for the `editor` and `administrator`?

```
// remove from everyone that isn't admin or editor
function taxonomy_for_admin_and_editor_only() {
   if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || !current_user_can( 'editor' ) ) {
       register_taxonomy( 'foobar', array() );
   }
}
add_action( 'init' , 'taxonomy_for_admin_and_editor_only' );
```

I've tried `add_action( 'admin' , 'taxonomy_for_admin_and_editor_only' );` with no luck either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When registering your taxonomy you can pass an argument called **capabilities**. Simply passing capabiities that only admins and editors have.

```
$args = array(
    'capabilities' => array( 'manage_options', 'edit_posts' )
);
register_taxonomy( 'foobar', 'post', $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor

Comment: While my answer explains why the code in the question isn't functioning, this answer is the proper way to do it

Comment: Awesome.  Just to clarify in the array you need to pass one for administrator and one for the editor?

Comment: @Darth_Vader correct. you can pass any number of capabilities into the array. So just ensure you have at least one capability for each role you wish to have access.

Comment: I think I found the solution and added it as answer for the next person.  I marked this as the accepted answer since it was what I needed for a solution.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

I never played with roles before so this was a fun learning experience.  I'm leaving this because I've spent a lot of time researching this area and this might help the next person.  I know my question is in regards to the taxonomy but I was confused with the issue so I wanted to test from a CPT level.  The correct hook was `admin_init` however it was still removing the taxonomy from the `administrator` and `editor` and I did not want that.

Before the answer I did run across "[Possible to hide Custom Post Type UI/Menu from specific User Roles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/possible-to-hide-custom-post-type-ui-menu-from-specific-user-roles)" but when I use a function like:

```
// hide from Contributors
function no_see_from_contributors() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) :
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); // Posts
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); // Tools
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); // Comments
    endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'no_see_from_contributors' );
```

create a test Contributor account, even though it is not visible from the menu a Contributor can still access this area by adding `edit.php`, `tools.php` or `edit-comments.php` in the URL.  I'm going to test for a solution to prevent this and make an edit with a solution if I find one.

Further research after this led to "[Restrict custom post type to only site administrator role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54959/restrict-custom-post-type-to-only-site-administrator-role)" and "[Remove Custom Post Type menu for non-administrator users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7290/remove-custom-post-type-menu-for-non-administrator-users)" which were great reads.  To learn more about capabilities you can visit [Codex: register post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and scroll down to `capability_type`.

You can reference the codex for the [Administrator](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator) and [Editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) on what roles to use in the array.

Final taxonomy:

```
function something_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Taxonomies', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'theme' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Taxonomy', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'theme' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'theme' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'theme' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'theme' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'theme' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'theme' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'theme' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'theme' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'theme' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'theme' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'theme' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'theme' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'theme' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'theme' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'theme' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'theme' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'theme' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'theme' ),
    );
    $capabilities = array(
        'edit_post'          => 'edit_pages',
        'read_post'          => 'edit_pages',
        'delete_post'        => 'edit_pages',
        'edit_posts'         => 'edit_pages',
        'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_pages',
        'delete_posts'       => 'edit_pages',
        'publish_posts'      => 'edit_pages',
        'read_private_posts' => 'edit_pages'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'capabilities'               => $capabilities,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_key', array( 'post', 'foo_key', 'bar_key' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'something_taxonomy', 0 );
```

What I used to remove the meta box from Contributors:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    function remove_metabox_for_non_admin_and_editor() {
        if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) || current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
            remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-foo_key_tag', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'foo_keyimagediv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'authordiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'foo_keycustom', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'authordiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            remove_meta_box( 'taxonomy_keydiv', 'foo_key', 'normal' );
            // remove pages
            remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_metabox_for_non_admin_and_editor' );
}
```

To find what the `$id` is for the custom meta box I used Chrome's inspect element to find the id it was creating.  I chose `admin_menu` instead of `admin_init` after reading "[What Wordpress hook fires first admin_init or admin_menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137866/what-wordpress-hook-fires-first-admin-init-or-admin-menu)"

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `admin_init` hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'taxonomy_for_admin_and_editor_only' );
```